# Pull new posts using feed

Tags: query-posts, urls, rss, feed

How can I query new posts from a website using the RSS/ATOM feed?
I mean how can I structure the query URL to do that (say bring me all new posts from the last 10 days)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All that I'm aware of out of the box is that you can limit the amount of posts in your feed. Go to Reading>Settings and change: Syndication feeds show the most recent to 10.

You can also customize feeds:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds